# Is there a way to download a url that changes content but not the url in Selenium with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to code a new **scraping** tool. I am already able to select radio buttons, fulfill search box and so on.

My current problem is to save this kind of url appointed below:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myJj3.jpg

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdUTA.jpg

Until now I already have tried the use of some modules like wget and urllib.request.

```
driver.get("https://www.tjrs.jus.br/buscas/jurisprudencia/?aba=jurisprudencia")

time.sleep(2)

datade = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@type='text'][@id='data_julgamento_de']")
datade[0].send_keys('20/04/2019')
datade[0].submit()

dataate = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@type='text'][@id='data_julgamento_ate']")
dataate[0].send_keys('30/04/2019')
dataate[0].submit()

time.sleep(10)

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='exibir_html']")

for k in range(0,len(links)): 
    print("cod_ementa["+str(k)+"]="+str(links[k].get_attribute('cod_ementa')))
    
links[0].click()

print(driver.current_url)

urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.tjrs.jus.br/buscas/jurisprudencia/exibe_html.php', "test.txt")
```

I want to download the content to a file like this: [html file of static url](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XkJ8Wl4FNwrYvf2Qrioljf7F2y0cEj85)!

Comment: write out the the driver.page_source to file.

Comment: That just give me the https://www.tjrs.jus.br/buscas/jurisprudencia/?aba=jurisprudencia html...

Answer (score 0):

Content is dynamically retrieved from an xhr call you can view in network tab. It returns json. You can simply do a POST request with requests to get all content and parse out as required.

```
import requests

data = {
  'action': 'consultas_solr_ajax',
  'metodo': 'buscar_resultados',
  'parametros': 'aba=jurisprudencia&realizando_pesquisa=1&pagina_atual=1&q_palavra_chave=&conteudo_busca=ementa_completa&filtroComAExpressao=&filtroComQualquerPalavra=&filtroSemAsPalavras=&filtroTribunal=-1&filtroRelator=-1&filtroOrgaoJulgador=-1&filtroTipoProcesso=-1&filtroClasseCnj=-1&assuntoCnj=-1&filtroReferenciaLegislativa=&filtroJurisprudencia=&filtroComarcaOrigem=&filtroAssunto=&data_julgamento_de=20%2F04%2F2019&data_julgamento_ate=30%2F04%2F2019&filtroNumeroProcesso=&data_publicacao_de=&data_publicacao_ate=&facet=on&facet.sort=index&facet.limit=index&wt=json&ordem=desc&start=0'
}

r = requests.post('https://www.tjrs.jus.br/buscas/jurisprudencia/ajax.php', data=data).json()
```